# PDF Parser won't find the Parser() class

Tags: php, pdf

Okay so to start I am using Xampp on windows.

I have tried installing with composer as on the documentation. The installation goes well and installs fine.

I have installed it into the directory of the website so the directory is like this.

C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\Website

I downloaded PDF Parser from GitHub and extracted it to the same directory.

I then moved the composer.json to the directory of the website, ran composer on cmd, installed it etc.

I then created a file and added this code

```
include 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Parse pdf file and build necessary objects.
$parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
$pdf    = $parser->parseFile('document.pdf');    
$text = $pdf->getText();
echo $text;
```

However I am receiving this error: Fatal error:

Uncaught Error: Class 'Smalot\PdfParser\Parser' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\Emails\readEmails.php

It can find the include but it won't find the class even though the pdfparser-master is in the same directory?

Any help would be awesome.

Thanks

Comment: Since you didn't install from Composer, I would guess that `vendor/autoload.php` either doesn't exist or doesn't contain know to load the PDF parsing library. You should install it with Composer if possible, or figure out how to use the library's own autoloading script/load files by hand.

Comment: vendor/autoload.php does exist, it is in the same directory as the website, however your saying installing pdf parser from composer is the correct way to do this, how would I do that, I ran composer update smalot/pdfparser but it didn't help me at all.

Comment: Perhaps try `composer install smalot/pdfparser`, not `update`? Also, looking at your path, you'd probably want to step back a few directories with `../` so you're including `vendor/autoload.php` from your **web root**, not from `/Emails`.

Comment: of course no idea why I did update and not install, I will give it a go when I am home later and let you know. Thanks for the prompt responses though I do appreciate it.